# How to count the number of documents with the specified field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider the below documents in a collection "project"

```
{
  _id:"1",
  "project_id":"1",
  "Name":"A",
  "type":"Description"
}

{
  _id:"2",
  "Name":"A",
  "project_id":"2",
  "type":"Paragraph"
}

{
  _id:"3",
  "Name":"A",
  "project_id":"1",
  "type":"Description"
}

{
  _id:"4",
  "Name":"A",
  "project_id":"3",
  "type":"Description"
}
```

I want to write a mongodb query where it has to count the number of documents with "type":"Description" for the "project_id":"1".

Comment: You write a [db.collection.countDocuments](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/) method to query a collection using various [Query Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/query/index.html) and get a count.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the count by using any of the following methods:

1. Using [db.collection.countDocuments(query, options)](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/)

```
db.collection.countDocuments({ "project_id": "1","type":"Description"})
```

It performs an aggregation of the document to return an accurate count

2. Using [db.collection.count(query, options)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)

```
db.collection.count({ "project_id": "1","type": "Description" })
```

Avoid using the db.collection.count() method without a query predicate since without the query predicate, the method returns results based on the collection’s metadata, which may result in an approximate count.

3. Using [aggregation pipeline stage $count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "project_id": "1",
      "type": "Description"
    }
  },
  {
    $count: "count"
  }
])
```

[MongoDB Query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xA7_F9aaktM)

PS: Replace the "collection" with your collection name.

Comment: Only `countDocuments` is guaranteed to be accurate and actually uses something like the aggregation pipeline behind the scenes.